# Use VirtualBox without ISO?

Tags: dual-boot, virtualbox, windows-7

I have Windows 7 and Ubuntu installed on my computer (dual booting).  I want to use the Zune software in Windows 7, but seeing as that is the only reason I need it, I want to use Virtalbox.  However, my computer didn't come with a CD/ISO for Windows 7, so I'm not sure how I would go about getting Virtalbox to boot into Windows 7.  Please help me out!

Answer (score 2):

You would have to buy Windows 7, insert the disc into your drive and then go into your storage settings for the VM and select the disc.

Comment: what if you have no dirve?! then your lost.

Comment: Then you put Windows in a USb just like Linux...

Comment: Just make an iso from this disk in a computer with a cd drive.  Or buy windows 7 as a download from the MS online store (US only AFAIK).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but i think your computer comes with a hidden recovery drive, most laptop have this feature.
I think you can use some special software to export the hidden recovery drive onto your other visible drives, then let VirtualBox take the windows files from where you stored them.
I'm sure you could create backup DVDs using the hidden recovery partition, but i'm not sure how the files would end up and if it could be picked up by VirtualBox. Just consider this solution before getting a Windows 7 DVD.

Comment: Note that MS licence policy does not allow to install Windows on more than one machine (the VM counts as well).

Comment: I tried this with a ThinkPad, and was unable to use the recovery CD/DVDs to reinstall in a VM. This might vary by manufacturer though.

Comment: From my experience (Acer laptop and XP, though), hidden partitions don't work with VB (even if you make a CD/DVD copy). Those are not only Windows but Windows + tons of your computer manufactor's software crap and VB is not able to recognize them.